# Were are they? Are there even any?

Tags: baking, vinegar, hot-chocolate

Were are the steps to make yogurt? I've been looking for 5 hours and ended up being late for making yogurt for lunch! I won't be back on this website again, Thats for sure

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is not a site for recipes, but rather cooking advice or trouble shooting, so I wouldn't go looking for recipes here. If you can tell us what problem with making yogurt you are having (besides lack of recipe), then we will be happy to advise.

Comment: "baking", "vinegar", "hot-chocolate" ... ? Interesting tags for a question about yogurt making ...

Answer (score 1):

In general to make yogurt you need 4 things - milk, a culture, temperature and time.

You can obtain a culture from any live-culture yogurt you can get from the supermarket. Look for ones that specifically say "live culture". The others will still contain the bacterial species you might find in yogurt, but have been pasteurized to improve shelf life.

For milk - I find that full-fat milk powder works best. So long as you can fully dissolve it in water, you can adjust amounts to suit thickness of the yogurt produced. Follow the guidelines on the outside of the packet to make the milk.

For temperature - warm is best, it needs to be fairly stable at around 37 Celsius (98 F) for the culture to grow rapidly and make the yogurt. Lower temperatures will have the same effect, just take a lot longer and increase the risk of unwanted bacterial and fungal species growing too. Too hot and the culture will not grow well or will be killed.

Time - this depends on the temperature. At around 37 Celsius, you will need to incubate for about 4-6 hours. Tip the yogurt on its side to determine it it has "set" so that you know if the culture has grown properly.